# Angular 14 update issues with Material

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

After updating our SPA from Angular 13 to Angular 14, at runtime we are receiving the following error:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy -> InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken mat-select-scroll-strategy!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:9091:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9258:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9258:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9258:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:22217:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3379:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3424:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10407:12)
    at _MatSelectBase_Factory (select.mjs:907:1)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.MatSelect_Factory [as factory] (select.mjs:1286:1)
```

We use a custom npm package that manages the Angular Material (version 13 is used there).
Basically, we cannot install Angular Material directly because it is provided by that package.

Before the Angular 14 migration, everything worked fine.
Is something changed with this new Angular 14 version? Thanks.

Package.js :

```
{
  "name": "APP_NAME",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck --port 4200",
    "build": "ng build --aot",
    "build:qa": "ng build --aot --configuration=qa",
    "build:uat": "ng build --aot --configuration=uat",
    "build:prod": "ng build --aot --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.2",
    "@CUSTOM_PACKAGE_WITH_ANGULAR_MATERIAL": "X.X.X",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-mask": "^14.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.33.0",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "latest",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest you to check all the material components that were used in the project, some of them require to import their module in AppModule in order for them to work, maybe this custom material package has a component that now requires it's module imported.

Comment: if I comment out mat-select, it works, until a modal is shown, then I get the same error, but related to Overlay injection. it's odd because we have a shared package with styles and custom widgets based on Angular Material, I can't simply install Material on all apps

Comment: MatSelect requires `MatSelectModule` and `MatInputModule`. And the modals require the `MatDialogModule` imported in the AppModule. Based on your troubleshoot I'd say both are missing (and if the mat-select is in a form-field then you also need to import `MatFormFieldModule`. These should be in that shared package that you are using since they are needed for the components to work. It is quite strange that they previously worked to be honest